# How to give read access permission for Firestore imageurl in Java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, file-io

I am able to access the Firestore image url on my browser window.
I want to convert this image url into BufferedImage after reading I have to find sub-image to get barcode value presented on my image.
Here is the code, I have connected with my bucket using Firestore and selecting few images from bucket based on conditions.

And rules for writing/reading is given as *allow read, write: if true;* in Firestore storage.

And initialized my FireBaseInitialize with key.json (service account details).

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imageUrl)); // imageUrl is contains path  (environment, bucket, database name)  & token
```

Getting below IIOException,

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1310)
```

How to give read permission for images in Firestore bucket in order to read by Java **ImageIO** class. I am not using android version. This is specific to Java.

I suspect if permission is missing I am unable to access collection itself, correct me if I am wrong ?

Note: For testing purpose I have changed the storage permission to access to all.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {  
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Still getting the same error, javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

Comment: Are you sure you can read from Firebase simply by using ImageIO? I think you need to incorporate the Firebase SDK and use the provided client to access the files. Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358940/how-to-get-firebase-working-with-java-backend
edit: Seems like there is a Rest API for Firebase that ought to be used with clients: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Firebase working with Java backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358940/how-to-get-firebase-working-with-java-backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javax.imageio.IIOException was thrown because the `File` class can only be instantiated with paths that are accessible through the local system, that does not include HTTP or HTTPS URIs.

Hopefully next version of Java would handle cloud things in a better way. If someone able to request for this feature from Java would be much appreciated.